# mathematics - exponentation in php - simple script

Tags: php, html, get, pow

Hello I need to create simple script which will do exponentiation of numbers that I'll give and also it **inform me if I'wont give a number or I'll leave empty space.**

I did something like that, but it show a the begining that "All fields must not be empty" and if I'll click compute without numbers I get "Wrong data" and it should be "All fields must not be empty"

Could someone fix it or tell me where is error?

Sorry if something is not understandable

Here is my script:

```html
<body>

<FORM action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
Base: <input type="text" name="number1" />
Exponent : <input type="text" name="number2" />
<input type="submit" value="compute!" name="Compute"/>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_GET ['number1']) || isset($_GET['number2'])) {

    if (is_numeric($_GET['number1']) && is_numeric($_GET['number2'])) {

        echo "{$_GET['number1']} ^ {$_GET['number2']} = ";
        echo pow($_GET['number1'], $_GET['number2']);
        echo "<BR>";

    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Wrong data<BR>";
    }
}
else 
{
    echo "All fields must not be empty<BR>";
}

?> 
<br />
<a href="index.php">Return!</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Indenting your code make make it easier to read, and easier to see what each of the nested `if` statements actually does

Comment: if in doubt about the version, use exp(b*ln(a)) for computing a^b. Also, you should only perform the calculation when both number1 and number2 are set (using && instead of ||). And check the value of submit button, to see if anything was submitted at all.

Comment: Note that `isset` doesn't necessarily do what you expect.... both `$_GET['number1']` and `$_GET['number2']` are __"set"__ (they exist and aren't NULL) but they may still contain empty strings

Comment: change isset to strlen($input)>=1 should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset($input)` will always return `true` because `$input` is still **set** even if empty...

So, `!empty($input)` will return `true` only if `$input` is ***not*** (see exclamation `!`) empty and therefore seems to me like a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Both of answers bellow are correct, but i would prefer to combine them.

Make sure, that you check if the button is clicked before you run your PHP code - so check with

```
if(isset($_GET['Compute']))
```

before

```
if (isset($_GET ['number1']) || isset($_GET['number2'])) {
```

as Maureen said

after that you have to check with !empty from Nadav S. with

```
if (!empty($_GET ['number1']) && !empty($_GET['number2']))
```

but please be sure you don't delete the line with the isset check. You also have to change the OR-operator || to an AND-operator &&. This line is needed to check if the script works as well. So you will check at this line, if the variable is SET. It could be, that by some fails you will not recieve the right variables, so the script would give out an error (you cant check with empty if the variable is not set).

Comment: Hmm Thank You it's working with `!empty` and `&&`, but if I'm using `if($_GET['Compute']){` I'm getting Notice: Undefined index: Compute in C:\xampp\htdocs\pot\dobra.php on line 15 This the line with `if($_GET['Compute']){`

Comment: I'm sorry for that dumb mistake. You have to check for `if(isset($_GET['Compute']))`. So your PHP will check, if the button is pressed. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a master programmer but I think I kinda understand your problem.

Your code already starts checking whether number1 and 2 exists when loading the page. Obviously when loading the page, they do not exist yet. And since you have and else on it, it will automatically echo All fields must not be empty when loading the page.

Try to check whether the button is pressed by sending form DATA on the button.
The name of the button is Compute. So let's do this!

```
    if($_GET['Compute') {
```

///////// This will check whether the button is pushed /////
 /// Place other codes here. ///

}

Now the page will start to execute the actual coding ONCE THE BUTTON is pressed.
Therefore it won't check whether number 1 and 2 are existent before clicking the button.

Considering the other problem, I do not know how, but I hope this helped a little bit.

Maureen

Answer (score 0):

try isset() and !empty() instead of just isset()